# GHC 8.0.1 errors from Writer and State monads

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm relatively new to Haskell and trying to port the UNIX wc program demonstrated in Kernighan and Ritchie using monadic composition, as shown in [*The Essence of the Iterator Pattern*](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf) by Jeremy Gibbons and Bruno C. d. S. Oliveira, and having some trouble getting it to compile. Here's my code:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Char

test :: Bool -> Integer
test b = if b then 1 else 0

ccmBody :: Char -> Writer Integer Char
ccmBody c = do
  tell 1
  return c

ccm :: String -> Writer Integer String
ccm = mapM ccmBody

lcmBody :: Char -> Writer Integer Char
lcmBody c = do
  tell(test(c == '\n'))
  return c

lcm' :: String -> Writer Integer String
lcm' = mapM lcmBody

wcmBody :: Char -> State (Integer, Bool) Char
wcmBody c = let s = not (isSpace c) in do
              (n,w) <- get
              put (n + test(not (w || s)), s)
              return c

wcm :: String -> State (Integer, Bool) String
wcm = mapM wcmBody

clwcm = ccm >=> lcm' >=> wcm
```

And the compiler errors:

```
wordcount.hs:10:3: error: …
    • No instance for (Monoid Integer) arising from a do statement
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: tell 1
       In the expression:
        do { tell 1;
             return c }
      In an equation for ‘ccmBody’:
          ccmBody c
            = do { tell 1;
                   return c }
wordcount.hs:33:26: error: …
    • Couldn't match type ‘StateT
                             (Integer, Bool) Data.Functor.Identity.Identity’
                     with ‘WriterT Integer Data.Functor.Identity.Identity’
      Expected type: String
                     -> WriterT Integer Data.Functor.Identity.Identity String
        Actual type: String -> State (Integer, Bool) String
    • In the second argument of ‘(>=>)’, namely ‘wcm’
      In the second argument of ‘(>=>)’, namely ‘lcm' >=> wcm’
      In the expression: ccm >=> lcm' >=> wcm
Compilation failed.
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong here in either case. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `Writer` monad to work, the object you're writing has to be an instance of [`Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html). `tell` uses `mappend` to add its argument to the running log.

For integers, however, there are at least two good choices for a `Monoid` instance. One of them is addition, with 0 as the unit element:

```
instance Monoid Int where
    mempty = 0
    mappend = (+)
```

and the other is multiplication with 1:

```
instance Monoid Int where
    mempty = 1
    mappend = (*)
```

How should the Haskell designers choose between these two options? They're both equally valid, and both useful in different situations. In the end they decided not to express an opinion, leaving `Int` without a `Monoid` instance of its own and instead providing two `newtype`s to allow you to choose which instance you want.

```
newtype Sum n = Sum { getSum :: n }
instance Num n => Monoid (Sum n) where
    mempty = Sum 0
    Sum x `mappend` Sum y = Sum (x + y)

newtype Product n = Product { getProduct :: n }
instance Num n => Monoid (Product n) where
    mempty = Product 1
    Product x `mappend` Product y = Product (x * y)
```

These two `newtype`s are found [in the `Data.Monoid` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#g:3). I'm guessing in your case you want to add up the numbers in the `Writer` monad, so all you should need to do is change all your type signatures from `Writer Integer` to `Writer (Sum Integer)`.

---

The other type error is GHC telling you that you can't compose a `Writer` action with a `State` action. You have `wcm :: State (Integer, Bool) String` and `ccm :: Writer Integer String`. Skim-reading your code, it looks like you're only using the `Integer` component of your state to add things up (I'm guessing it's meant to take part in the running total along with the `Writer` bits?), so I would consider using the *monad transformer* version of `State`:

```
wcm :: StateT Bool (Writer Integer) String
```

and then using `lift` to bring the plain old `Writer Integer` monads into the `StateT`-enriched context.

If you're not used to monad transformers yet, the other option is to write everything in the `State (Integer, Bool)` monad.

Comment: Indeed, `State (Integer, Bool)` is likely better anyway. `Writer` doesn't really work well with things like `Sum Integer`.

Comment: @dfeuer Could you quantify that? Are you talking about laziness?

Comment: Yes. Even `Control.Monad.Writer.Strict` is lazy in the "log". You could implement your own instance of `MonadWriter` and use that, but the conversion to a tail-recursive form will end up making it look like `State`. `newtype WriterT' w m a = WriterT' (StateT w m a) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad); instance (Monoid w, Monad m) => MonadWriter w (WriterT' w m) where tell a = WriterT $ modify' (<> a)`. I'm not sure if all the other effects are supported, but probably. In the end, you basically land back in `State` land, with some stuff under the hood that could be fussy to verify.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to just use `State` for everything as I think that makes the most sense. But I'm still not sure I'm composing them correctly because I get a typing error trying to just test it with a string in GHCi: `evalState clwcm "this is a test, this is only a test"` yields `Couldn't match type ‘String -> State (Integer, Bool) String’ with ‘StateT [Char] Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a’` `Expected type: State [Char] a` `Actual type: String -> State (Integer, Bool) String`

Comment: Turns out I confused the code in the paper. It doesn't compose the monads using kleisli arrows, but through product functors like this: `data Product' m n a = Product { pfst :: m a, psnd :: n a } deriving (Show)`
`prod :: (Functor m, Functor n) => (a -> m b) -> (a -> n b) -> (a -> Product' m n b)` `prod f g x = Product' (f x) (g x)`. I'm not sure I understand what they're getting at with that, but I didn't need them to simulate the results of the C version, which essentially just returns a triple.